# Create a 7z archive with some subfolders, preserving directory structure and including only files with certain extension

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip, archiving

I have a main folder, inside that I have many folders, with many different files inside each folder. 
My goal is to create an archive, with only a subset of the subfolders, including only files with a specific extension. Suppose you have this structure, where A is the main folder, B,C and D are its subfolders.

> A
>
> --> B (foo.png, bar.png, ret.jpg)
>
> --> C (example.png)
>
> --> D (fritz.png)

What I want is:

> archive.7z
>
> --> B (foo.png, bar.png)
>
> --> C (example.png)

I am under linux, and cannot find a way to do this. Any hints?
I tried this

> 7z a archive.7z -ir! A/B*.png -ir!A/C*.png

But only compress files with name starting with B or C..

Answer (score 0):

A *general* approach is to replicate `A` in another location with only a subset of its original content. Then archive (compress) the replica as a whole.

Hints:

- Replication can be done with a tool designed for backups (e.g. `rsync`) which provides options to include and/or exclude files or directory trees.
- If possible, create hardlinks instead of independent copies. This requires operating within the same filesystem.
- Copying/hardlinking more than you need and then removing excessive files (possibly by hand) is a valid approach.

Useful commands (not necessarily fully portable):

- `cp -lr A/ B` – copy directory recursively, hardlink files.
- `find B/ -type f ! -iname '*.png' -delete` – remove all files but `*.png` (case insensitive matching) in `B/`.
- `find B/ -type d -empty -delete` – remove empty directories.
- `rm -r B/garbage/` – remove unwanted directory along with its content.

There is nothing specific to `7z` in this approach. It will work with any archiver.

Answer (score 0):

Though 2 years from the original post, I will provide my answer in case someone ends up here.

Mind that `7z a` will scan and add files under the current directory.
Assuming current directory is the parent of A, OP's code would read:

```
7z a archive.7z -ir\!A/B/*.png -ir\!A/C/*.png
```

More generally, we could also include every .png file, excluding `-x` any subfolder named D:

```
7z a output.zip -ir\!*.png -xr\!*/D/
```

And so on with combinations of wildcards, hope it helps.